# Bypass `-C` flag when unzipping tar archive

Tags: devops, tar, archive, system-administration

I have a `.tar.gz` archive with the following structure:

```
opt/client/py/utils/mappings/templates/config.json
opt/
opt/mag/
opt/mag/sw/
opt/mag/sw/apps/
opt/mag/sw/apps/service/
opt/mag/etc/
opt/mag/etc/service.environment
opt/mag/etc/service.toml
```

And this `.tar.gz` archive is extracted using this command:

```
tar -zxf ../service.tar.gz -C opt/mag/ --strip-components=2
```

Thee issue is this will extract the `opt/client/py/utils/mappings/templates/config.json` file inside `opt/mag` so it will become: `opt/mag/py/utils/mappings/templates/config.json` which is obviously wrong. Notice the removal of `opt/client/` by `--strip-components=2`.

**The issue is that I cannot change the unzip command**

I've tried to hack it around by inserting 2 dummy directories to bypass `--strip-components=2` something like this:

```
dummy1/dummy2/opt/client/py/utils/mappings/templates/config.json
opt/
opt/mag/
opt/mag/sw/
opt/mag/sw/apps/
opt/mag/sw/apps/service/
opt/mag/etc/
opt/mag/etc/service.environment
opt/mag/etc/service.toml
```

This way `--strip-components=2` will remove `dummy1/dummy2` and the config file will be extracted to `/opt/mag/opt/client/py/utils/mappings/templates/config.json` which is still wrong, because that `-C opt/mag` will force the extraction inside `opt/mag`.

Given the fact that **I cannot change the unzip command** is there anyway to bypass the `-C` switch or some way to hack it around?

**Also, I cannot edit or move files on the container where this archive is extracted**

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Ok, I'll move it there. Should I delete it from SO?

Comment: You could define a `tar` function that removes the `-C` option and its parameter and then passes the remaining arguments to the real `tar` command.

Comment: I cannot do stuff on the container where this is deployed

Comment: Why can't you change the command being used to extract the tar file? If it's in a script, functions you declare in your own shell won't affect it.

Comment: Then what kind of answer are you expecting? You can't change how the `tar` program processes its arguments.

Comment: I thought there was some workaround

Comment: Where is `config.json` supposed to be extracted to? There's no way to treat it as an absolute pathname if the extraction command doesn't say so.

Comment: in `/opt/client/py/utils/mappings/templates/config.json`

Comment: Unless the extraction uses the `-P` option, all names in the tarfile are treated as relative. There's no way for you to override that, it would be an incredible security violation if you could (since you could force files to be written outside of the user's target directory, possibly into system directories like `/etc`).

Comment: Do you have any influence on how the script is started?

Comment: Unfortunately, no